# Docking station sound doesn't work on Dell D830 with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, dell-latitude

**EDIT: I can only mark one answer as the correct one but the actual solution was a combination of two comments (updating the BIOS to A15 AND installing the Sigmatel audio drivers).**

I have a Dell Latitude D830 laptop that is running Windows 7 Enterprise x64.  I connect to a docking station during the day with multiple monitors, a keyboard and a mouse.  Everything runs with no problems including most of the docking station ports (usb, monitors, etc.)  However, the sound port from the docking station does not work since the upgrade to Windows-7.  Even with the laptop plugged in, the sound always comes out of the laptop, not the headphones plugged into the docking station.

Here's what I've tried:

I've seen other issues like via Google this that seem to be mostly unanswered. I found one or two that referenced using the Vista x64 drivers, especially the Nvidia drivers.

I do not have an Nvidia chipset but I've reinstalled the sound drivers and that has not helped.

I don't have a support contract and considering the cost is usually high to call Dell, that's not an option.

Dell's forums are pretty much a wasteland and I've found no help there.

Since this is a docking station I thought I might need to try the SATA or Intel chipset drivers from the dell site instead, however I'm not really sure and I need to work on this laptop in the meantime.  I can't really afford the downtime to experiment with random drivers all day in case they turn out to be incompatible (Dell still hasn't added Windows 7 to their support site as far as I can tell).

Does anyone have any other ideas?  Has anyone had this issue and solved it?  If so, how?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar experience to yours.  I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a D830 with a docking station and the drivers (Sigmatel 6.10.0.5614, A09 for STAC 92xx C-Major HD Audio) wouldn't install saying the device didn't exist.  However after I upgraded my bios to A15 these same drivers installed without issue and now the jack on my docking station is fully functional.

Wasn't sure if the drivers didn't work as in they didn't install... or didn't work as in they didn't change any behavior after they installed.

You can disregard if you're already running A15.

Comment: I deleted my first comment to add some info. The new A15 BIOS DID fix my issue, when it was combined with the previously suggested Sigmatel audio drivers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the D/Dock Expansion station,I had the same problem until I installed the 64 bit Vista Sigmatel drivers from here:

[1]: http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&deviceid=8907&libid=3&releaseid=R171788&vercnt=2&formatcnt=0&SystemID=Latitude D830&servicetag=9S0DMD1&os=WV64&osl=en&catid=-1&dateid=-1&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&impid=-1 "64 bit Sigmatel Drivers for D830"

And yes - the reboot is required after you install these.  Once installed, you should have sound from either the SPDIF or the headphone jack.

Comment: Thanks but please see the other person who suggested this (below).  I have already tried these drivers and they did not work for my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The Vista drivers for the Sigmatel sound device solves the problems on Windows 7 32 bit.

Get the from the [Dell website](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WV64&catid=3&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=LATITUDE+D830&hidos=WV64&hidlang=en&TabIndex=)

Comment: Thanks but I tried the sound drivers from the Dell drivers and they didn't make any difference on the 64-bit version.

Comment: Just wanted to leave an update on this.  The Sigmatel drivers that did not work before DO work if you also install the new A15 BIOS release (suggested above).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In win 7 the audiodriver used for the soundcard in a Dell D830 is a generic one from windows, it does not support the extra options like using the spdif from the dockingstation. That's why you have to install the proper soundcard drivers (in this case the Vista 64 drivers work fine).

Answer (score 0):

D830, Windows 7 Ultimate x64 T7500

My Dell docking station is Model PR01x (PA-10/PA-13), which is the driver I search for on the Dell site for my specific model. I found a Vista x64 driver that worked...It allowed the sound to pass from the docking station through the external speakers. The driver I downloaded extract in a folder name 2Y0VM. After running the setup executable, I rebooted and the problem was solved. GOOD LUCK! PS. a lot of the drivers work for several different Dell models...D830, D630, D620, etc.